# Permissões de acesso no Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, acl

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema no **Laravel 4** com base em tutoriais e documentação oficial do Laravel. Não tenho visto algo relacionado a permissões de acesso *(ACL)* no Laravel. Sabendo que meu sistema terá vários recursos disponíveis, como: Notícias, Produtos, Administração de Usuários, entre outros, como eu poderia fazer de forma prática uma página onde eu insira as permissões por módulo que cada usuário terá acesso?

Penso em algo onde eu cadastre níveis de permissões *(Admin, User, Editor)* e depois, no cadastro do usuário, eu vinculo algum nível. Por outro lado, na hora de cadastrar um usuário eu poderia ter opções de *checkbox* com os tipos de permissões *(editar, visualizar, excluir)* de cada módulo específico, e selecionaria o desejado para cada usuário. Neste caso, eu optaria em dar permissões individuais por usuário ou selecionaria um nível específico para aquele usuário.

Alguém tem alguma base que eu poderia seguir para desenvolver este recurso?

Comment: Eu utilizo o pacote Verify L4 pela facilidade que encontrei desde o princípio... http://docs.toddish.co.uk/verify-l4/

Comment: Temos uma outra opção que é o conjunto Confide+Entrust https://github.com/Zizaco/confide (autenticação)<br>
https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust (permissões de acesso) Tenho usado, documentação clara e atende muito bem.

Comment: Eu fiz um sistema de Acl na mão em Laravel, mas existem algumas bibliotecas que fazem isso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode experimentar o **Sentry 2** - uma solução robusta para autenticação, autorização e ACL. Essa biblioteca começou como um *bundle* do Laravel, mas evoluiu para um pacote que pode ser instalado em outros frameworks. Segue o link específico para integração com Laravel 4:

https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/installation/laravel-4

E segue o link para a documentação sobre permissões:

https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentry/permissions

---

Se você preferir construir a sua própria solução, ao invés de usar uma solução pronta, minha sugestão é usar três tabelas:

1. A sua tabela de **usuários**.
2. Uma tabela de **ações**.
3. Uma tabela de conexão *many-to-many* ligando as duas ("**usuarios_acoes**")

Você também pode considerar:

1. Uma tabela de **níveis**.
2. Uma tabela de conexão *many-to-many* ligando os níveis com as acções ("**niveis_acoes**")

Nesse caso, você pode ou **eliminar** a tabela "usuarios_acoes" e guardar apenas um "id_nivel" na tabela "usuarios", aplicando exclusivamente as permissões do nível... ou então **manter** a tabela "usuarios_acoes" e aplicar um nível a um usuário - o que copiaria as ações do "nível" para o "usuário", mas ainda assim permitindo um ajuste fino individual. Essa seria a versão mais robusta.

Você terá o trabalho de definir as ações da tabela "ações", e de definir quais ações cada "nível" pode executar e/ou quais ações cada usuário pode executar.

---

Além da estrutura e armazenamento no banco de dados, você vai precisar de algum filtro ou outro mecanismo que verifique se o usuário tem permissão ou não de executar determinada ação.

E, num grau mais "fino" ainda, você poderá querer que a própria interface apresente ou não elementos de interação, baseado nas permissões.

Eu já montei um CMS com tudo isso que estou descrevendo acima - cada usuário vê apenas as opções no menu e os botões das ações que têm permissão. Ficou bem bacana. Com certeza, no back-end o sistema verifica as permissões - pois se a diferença ficasse apenas na interface, um usuário teria a possibilidade de ser bem sucedido ao forjar uma requisição HTTP de uma ação que ele não tem permissão para realizar.

Eu fui além: um usuário que tem a permissão de dar/remover permissões dos outros usuários pode apenas "delegar" aquelas ações das quais ele mesmo tem permissão para executar. Na interface, feita em ExtJS, aparece um "checkbox-tree", onde é possível marcar/desmarcar todo um grupo de ações de uma vez, ou cada uma individualmente...

Ficam aí as dicas e comentários.